# Token error with impersonnating user

Tags: symfony, session

I'm building an authentification system with both roles and users provided by a SGBD.

The authentification works fine, now I would like to implement the impersonnating functionnality.

I've a problem with my impersonnating user roles : a custom role from my database is missing. Null is given in place.

With debugging mode I see my authorization running the decide function on voters. The token passed to the `RoleHierarchyVoter` contains only one entry:

[image]

(note that the length is 2, strange...)

I also debug the creation of the token, I see that roles are well passed to the token on creation:

[image]

I suspect a limitation on session persistance (as far as I understand the token is serialized into the session), but I don't know much about Symfony session...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to enable in order for Symfony to handle impersonating users. Since i'm not sure what your config looks like, there is a great cookbook article that walks you through the steps:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html

You should also look at how you are serializing your user. There is a github issue that is different, but along the same lines as the problem you're describing: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3085

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#understanding-serialize-and-how-a-user-is-saved-in-the-session

Once you've done that, if it's still not working, try creating a listener on the security.switch_user event and seeing if it's even firing. If it is, you should be able to debug there to see what's going on.

Comment: The impersonnating fonction already works fine, but impersonnated user's token has missing roles.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. There is a github issue that is similar (but with the switch user role missing) and may require some changes to how the serialize function is defined in your user entity/document or someone reporting a change to refreshUser in your user provider. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3085 I would also try an event listener and debugging the targetUser at the beginning of the security.switch_user event to see if the role exists there. The event listener has saved me several times when debugging various impersonation issues.

Comment: Ok, it's not really the same problem than the Github issue you link, but the idea to only serialize the username works for me (althought I see the missing role into the serialized string, there is no sense...). Thank you very much!

Comment: You should add your comment's content to your answer in order to accept it.